# Pandas (python) Extract sum of values in different rows using one column as filter

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

.Im learning data analysis and i would like to do the following. Im using pandas with google collaboratory:

I have next table:

| name | A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | a | c | d |
| Second | b | a | a |
| First | a | c | d |
| First | a | c | d |
| First | a | c | d |
| Second | b | a | a |

I wish to sum every repeated value in columns "A1" to "A3" using the "name" (index) column as a filter. So the result i want is something like:

| name | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 4 | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| Second | 4 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I have tried: data.groupby('A1').size() but first i dont know how to tell pandas to show me those result divides by group of the names in column 2

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried

Comment: You should share a minimum reproducible example. Nobody is going to replicate your csv table. Also, share the code you try so far. Regards.

Comment: I hope i did a better job explaining myself

Comment: You say the example output isn't correct... what IS your desired output from your example input?

Comment: The question is now complete, the output is correct now. As it shows in the example is the way im trying to get

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
       A1 A2 A3
name
First   a  c  d
Second  b  a  a
```

Doing:

```
out = (df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1, result_type='expand')
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
        a  b  c  d
name
First   1  0  1  1
Second  2  1  0  0
```

Comment: What if on column name I have again multiple times "First", "Second" and other names repeated in several rows and i just want the summary for every unique name